# Am I presenting my viewControllers correctly?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an app which requires the user to login first before using the rest of the service.

This app is made out of tab bar controller with 4 tab bar items. All these 4 tab bar items has navigation controller.

Right now, I am presenting the loginViewController modally. I implemented a 'Remember Me' feature during login which will the user automatically be logged in the next time he re-launches the app. I do this by saving a indicator using NSUserDefaults and during viewDidLoad, checks for whether did the user opted for 'remember me' and present loginViewController modally if needed.

when the user logs out, I will then present loginViewController modally again and remove the NSUserDefaults. But then this will make the rest of the viewController of the tabBarController remain the same state as before the user logs out, which means when user logs in again it will not be a fresh copy. How do I make sure it's a fresh copy when ever the user logs in? Meaning the textFields and all, should not shown amendments made during previous logins.

All in all, I want to load a fresh copy of the tabBarController viewController whenever the user logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to send an `NSNotification` on logout and have all the views which need to reload their information observe that notification and do the update.

Another way would be to update each view's data on `viewDidAppear`.  The main downside with this method is that it will update every time, whether they logged out or not.

The notification way works like this:

In the logout view controller:

```
if (userDidLogout)
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: USER_LOGOUT_NOTIFICATION];
}
```

In the view controllers that need to know:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(updateMyData:) name: USER_LOGOUT_NOTIFICATION object: nil]

//...

- (void) updateMyData: (NSNotification*) note
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This works great, just that I obverse the event when the user logins instead. It would be weird to show the changes when the user logs out.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone is a "personal" device. It's not a web browser. A browser is different. On iPhone, avoid having an explicit logout if possible, or make it extremely difficult to find the logout button.
Facebook, Twitter, Foursquare all do this. Your phone is always with you and privacy conscious users are going to set a unlock password. Even other wise a lost phone can be wiped remotely (unlike a browser).

Think mobile when developing for a mobile device. Not every functionality you have on your web app needs to be implemented on the mobile device.

Having said that, if you still need a logout mechanism, nsnotifications are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't quite get why would you wanna 'hide' the logout button. There's no harm in letting the user logout if he/she choose to, isn't it?

Comment: There is no harm, but there is no need for that. Unless you lend your phone to someone who might use your app for a while

Comment: While I agree that the iPhone SHOULD be a personal device, they often fall into the hands of others, sometimes those of a prankstering sort.  Surely you've seen facebook posts clearly not written by the owner (i.e., "I love my girlfriend SO MUCH!  She is the best woman in the world", etc., blah blah.  :)  Letting the user log out is a reasonable option, just as the user choosing not to log out is a reasionable option.

Comment: So do you always logout of *every* single app on your iPhone? Ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

On pressing the `logout` button, make sure that you deallocate all active views. When you log back in, create a allocate a fresh set of views.

You can do the check for the `login` or `logout` with `NSUserDefaults` and the whole process have to be logically sync. The only thing you need to be worried about is properly deallocating all views and removing them appropriately when you log back again. Make sure that there are no memory leaks and your view controllers follow Apple's guidelines for  [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) .

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

viewWillAppear gets called everytime you open the Tab. you can reload view contents in viewWillAppear.

this solutions reloads the view every time user opens the view. there is better way to do this by saving last User State, So everytime user comes on the view, check if UserState (i.e. LoggedIn/LoggedOut) if it matches then no need to reload, if it doesn't reload the view.